# Some Images are not loading in localhost

Tags: javascript, html, localhost

I checked everything in html and css and now im putting in a localhost but only few images are showing up
These are the images not showing
[image]

and this image is from same page
[image]

Here are the links given

[image: Images which are not showing]

Link for images which are shown

[image: Images which are shown]

Help me i cannot understand why some are working and some are not

Comment: I'm on thin ice here, but [having "naked" precent characters in URL:s](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.1) seems like begging for trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your folder `60% off` contains both a `%` sign and a space sign, both being signs you should not use in links. Changing the name of the folder and thus the links should work